# settext on text field based on query on access

Tags: ms-access

I do have a query that I get what I want from it. but I want to set a test field on a form the value I get from the query. Once I type the following on the control source:

```
=[TheQuery]![College_Name]
```

and once I turn the view to the form view I get this in the textfield:

```
#Name?
```

Knowing that once I run the query direct I get the right result but I'm not sure to populate a text field with the query result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try

```
=Dlookup("College_Name", "TheQueryName")
```

search for `Dlookup` and you can learn more about how to use it.